# How to lock screen from command line in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, autohotkey

The following command is mentioned around other places:

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

or

```
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

but I couldn't make the command work in cmd.exe (Administrator mode).

In Windows 7, this is how I achieved what I wanted in autohotkey script
    RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System, DisableLockWorkstation, 0

```
Sleep, 500
DllCall("LockWorkStation")
Sleep, 2000
RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 
Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System, DisableLockWorkstation, 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tired both the commands manually and it worked for me with out any issues both in normal and admin privileged cmd in 8.1 OS .

> rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation

or

> C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation

check whether it is prompting any error message while executing the command and debug based on the error message

Comment: I found out that I needed to run my autohotkey scrip in admin mode